# Dialogflow system entity sys.any adds space before number in alphanumeric text

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to capture username in an intent called `Get_Username` where I have `username` parameter of `sys.any` entity type.

[image]

It works perfectly for all alphabetic or all numeric user names. However when I have alphanumeric username like ravi1, the extracted queryText contains a space before the number "ravi 1"

```
{
  "responseId": "7a505f10-5f2d-4bc3-bba5-ca05baaae4e5-b55300fa",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "ravi 1",
    "parameters": {
      "username": "ravi 1"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
...
}
```

Has anyone encountered such issue before? If yes, what is the solution to fix this?

Comment: usually username don't contain the space, simply you can remove space from your backend

Comment: on above json payload i can see ` "queryText": "ravi 1",` is `ravi 1` so its taking that as `@sys.any` as parameter

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya The usernames in backend system are without space e.g. "ravi1". Dialogflow request adds a space before the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original input with $[any].original

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-actions-parameters#original

Comment: unfortunately the original value also contains a space: "parameters": `{
          "username": "ravi 1",
          "username.original": "ravi 1"
        }`

Comment: That is super strange. Tryed myself. 
with ravi1 -> "parameters": { "username": "ravi 1"}
with anything else like ravi2, ravi3 -> "parameters": {"username": "ravi2"}

Edit: It seems 2 to 9 works as expected while any other number auto corrected with space before dialogflow gets called. If you check dialogflow history you will see as user typed with space. Feels like a bug.

Comment: Update -> Instead of Intent you can use fallback intent with context. You can acces user input from queryText. Ex output ->  {
  "queryText": "rav1",
  "parameters": {}, ... }